# Toggling LEDs in a respond to a counter at different scenarios

Tags: button, arduino, scheduled-tasks, counter, led

I am trying to toggle leds on and off based on two scenarios.

1. a counter.(input from two buttons - one for counting up and the other for counting down)
2. a specific time for led to be ON

if counter is equal to 1: turn ON led 1 for x amount of time (specify at index 0 of the Time array) - all other leds are off;

if counter is equal to 2:  turn off the previous led that was ON (even if the specify time of ON for that led was not elapsed) then turn ON led 2 for x amount of time.

the above should be same for all 5 indexes.

here is the code I have got so far for counting the button presses:

```
//Buttons//

const uint8_t MINBTNCOUNT = 0;
const uint8_t MAXBTNCOUNT = 4;


//Button1// count up
uint8_t buttonPin = 2;       
uint8_t buttonPressCount = 0;
uint8_t lstbuttonPressCount = 0;
uint8_t PUSHED = 0;
unsigned long timePushed = 0;
uint8_t currentButtonState = HIGH;
uint8_t lastButtonState = HIGH;
uint32_t millisTimePress = 0; 
//Button2// count down
uint8_t buttonPin2 = 3;
uint8_t buttonPressCount2 = 0;
uint8_t lstbuttonPressCount2 = 0;
uint8_t PUSHED2 = 0;
unsigned long timePushed2 = 0;
uint8_t currentButtonState2 = HIGH;
uint8_t lastButtonState2 = HIGH;
uint32_t millisTimePress2 = 0; 


////Leds/////
const int ledPins[] ={4,5,6,7,8}; // array of leds pins
const int numOfLeds =  (sizeof(ledPins) / sizeof(ledPins[0])); // size of Leds


//time translating//
#define sec * 1000
#define min * 60000
#define ms * 1

// LEDS ON Time Lengths //
const unsigned long ledOnTime[] = {19 sec, 44 sec, 9 sec, 7 sec, 33 sec};


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  
    pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(buttonPin2, INPUT_PULLUP);
    
   // setting up the digital pins for the leds to be an output //
  for (int j = 0; j < numOfLeds; j++)
  {
    pinMode(ledPins[j], OUTPUT);
  }
}


void loop() {
  buttonPress1 ();
  buttonPress2 ();
}



void buttonPress1 ()
{
    byte currentButtonState = digitalRead (buttonPin);
  
    if (lastButtonState != currentButtonState)  {
        lastButtonState = currentButtonState;
         delay (35);             // debounce


        //******************
        //has the switch been pushed ?
        if (currentButtonState == PUSHED)
        {
           //record the time the switch closed
           timePushed = millis();
          
        }
        //******************
    //switch has been released
    else
    {
      //calculate the time the switch was closed
      timePushed = millis() - timePushed;
      
      if(timePushed < 500)
      {
        buttonPressCount++;
        if( buttonPressCount == 0)
  {
    buttonPressCount = 4;
  }
  if( buttonPressCount == 5)
  {
    buttonPressCount = 1;
  }
        Serial.print("button count: ");
        Serial.println(buttonPressCount);
      }   
    }
  }
}

void buttonPress2 ()
{
    byte currentButtonState2 = digitalRead (buttonPin2);
  
    if (lastButtonState2 != currentButtonState2)
    {
        lastButtonState2 = currentButtonState2;
         delay (35);             // debounce

        //******************
        //has the switch been pushed ?
        if (currentButtonState2 == PUSHED2)
        {
           //record the time the switch closed
           timePushed2 = millis();
          
        }
        //******************
    //switch has been released
    else
    {
      //calculate the time the switch was closed
      timePushed2 = millis() - timePushed2;
      
      if(timePushed2 < 500)
      {
        buttonPressCount--;
        if( buttonPressCount == 0)
  {
    buttonPressCount = 4;
  }
  if( buttonPressCount == 5)
  {
    buttonPressCount = 1;
  }
        Serial.print("button count: ");
        Serial.println(buttonPressCount);
      }
           
    }
  }
}
```

I try to add another main function for toggling the LEDS based on a counter
and based on the ledOnTimearray

Here is my failed attempting:

```
void ledToggle()
{
  for(int i = 0; i < MAXBTNCOUNT; i++)
  {
  if(counter != lstcounter)
  {
    Serial.print("counter:");
    Serial.println(counter);
    lstcounter = counter;
     
    if(millis() - timeButtonPressed <= ledOnTime[i])
    {
      Serial.print(ledOnTime[i]);
      digitalWrite(ledPins[i], HIGH);
    }
 
  }
   if(millis() > timeButtonPressed +  ledOnTime[i] || counter != lstcounter)
    {
     digitalWrite(ledPins[i], LOW);   
    }
}
}
```

Thanks for helping!

I have tried to write a for loop I named

```
void ledToggle()
```

but without success.